# Swap Windows 10 Home to Pro

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have two PCs, both running Windows 10, however, one has the Pro edition, and the other doesn't. I wanted to know if it was possible to swap the License Key, I tried entering them into opposite computers but got this error:

> The product key didn't work. Check it and try again.

Comment: I think that you can use a key only once...

Comment: If they are OEM licenses then no.

Comment: @MichaelBay No, they are not OEM licenses, I purchased these licenses myself.

Comment: Retail licenses can be used in different hardware but not at the same time and require activation.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, which is why I'm asking if anyone has found a way to 'swap' license keys.

Comment: The process is you unregister the current key, then registry a new key, the Windows 10 Professional installation will have to be wiped and Windows 10 Home installed.  Windows 10 Home can be upgraded to Windows 10 Professional.

Comment: But I tried that... and I still got the error, could you link me to a guide, or provide more concreate steps.